# ¿Cómo transformar una Tabla en un triangulo?

Tags: r

Tengo una estructura como la siguiente:

```
datos <- read.table(header = T, text = "
                    anno mes venta
                    1999 12 5
                    1999 36 10
                    1999 24 5
                    2000 12 10
                    2000 24 20
                    2000 36 35
                    3000 12 40
                    3000 36 45
                    1999 12 50")
```

Me gustaría poder obtener el siguiente triangulo:

```
anno    12  24  36
1999    55  5   10
2000    10  20  35
3000    40  NA  45
```

El problema lo tengo el dato del último año (3000/36) que me lo pone en el mes 24 dejándome el 36 con un NA.

El codigo que tengo generado es el siguiente:

```
datos<-datos[order(datos$anno, datos$mes),]
datos2 <- datos %>%  
  group_by(anno, mes) %>% 
  summarise(ventas=sum(venta))

d2 <- datos2 %>% 
  select(anno, ventas) %>% 
  group_by(anno) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(rn, ventas)
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema lo tienes en la forma que planteas el `spread()`, realmente es mucho más sencillo a partir de los datos agrupados, hacer directamente: `spread(mes, ventas)`. El código completo te quedaría así:

```
datos %>% 
    group_by(anno, mes) %>% 
    summarise(ventas=sum(venta)) %>% 
    spread(mes, ventas)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   anno [3]
   anno  `12`  `24`  `36`
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  1999    55     5    10
2  2000    10    20    35
3  3000    40    NA    45
```